# How to console a change from controller to directive controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Following is the code which is running fine, with no issues. The only thing I am not able to get is that -

How do I console the `console.log("CHECK ",vm.testvar);` everytime whenever button hits.

Working Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/BGdGgGaDXlKiZq2aaN00?p=preview

script.js -

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.test = 'my test string from controller';

  $scope.clicked = function() {
    $scope.test = 'New - ' + Date.now();
  };
})

myApp.directive('mydir', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      testvar: '='
    },
    template: '<h1>Test Directive - {{vm.testvar}}</h1>',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    replace: true,
    bindToController: true,
    controller: function () {
      var vm = this;

      console.log("CHECK ",vm.testvar);
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish, for the controller to call that console log?

Comment: He's wanting to log out the `vm.testvar` each time the button is clicked.  Basically eliciting a response from within the directive via an outside controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this but the quickest way and probably the most *angular 1.**-ish is to use the `$scope.$watch` method:

```
controller: function ($scope) {
  var vm = this;

  $scope.$watch( 'vm.testvar', function(newValue){ 
    console.log( 'cHanged', newValue)
  })

  console.log("CHECK ",vm.testvar);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KsrG5lgmtyKSGce5HZ6F?p=preview

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of smart directives that have isolate scope and custom controllers.  I DO use them, but I try to defer to `$parse` for most UXs.

Comment: Can you pass some links that I look into for this as I just started playing with directives in AngularJS

Comment: Sure.  I put this on gist because it's fairly extensive.  It's not specific to directives per se  https://gist.github.com/jusopi/1350509a85d63601a060

Answer (score 1):

You could pass $scope to the controller and put a watch on vm.testvar. Then whenever vm.testvar changes, it will call its function.

```
controller: function (scope) {
  var vm = this;

  $scope.$watch('vm.testvar', function() {
     console.log("CHECK ",vm.testvar);
  });
}
```